# Combining an row index(variable) with a column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have already found the row index of a cell using VBA code. But I now I need to find an average of values in the cells from an index to another index. To find average, I know i can use application.worksheetfunction.average() but how do I combine the column and row index. The row index is a variable while the column is B for example.

For example, I need to find the average between startIndex to endIndex

Code:`application.worksheetfunction.average("BstartIndex:BendIndex").`

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Average("B" & startIndex & ":B" & endIndex)`

Basically, what you want to do is concatenate all components of the range string to insert into the function call. You cannot refer to variables inside a string in VBA, to my knowledge.